# Disable Slim's double equals (==) raw output operator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss, slim-lang

Slim's double equals (`==`) allows you to output text without HTML escaping. I'd like to disable this feature, forcing myself to use single equals (`=`), which has HTML escaping built in. Is that possible?

I want to disable double equals because it's difficult to search for when auditing for XSS vulnerabilities. It's much easier to search for `raw` or `html_safe`.

Comment: A quick review of the source suggests that you'd have to change the [`@quoted_attr_re` and `@code_attr_re` regexes in `Slim::Parser`](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/blob/master/lib/slim/parser.rb#L83). Of course, those instance variables are set in `Slim::Parser#initialize` so you'd have to edit the source or somehow call `instance_variable_set` to change them between `Slim::Parser.new` and when the parser starts parsing, or attempt to monkey patch `initialize`, or subclass and get Slim to use your subclass. I could be wrong, I only spent a couple minutes wandering around the source.